# Android - Call to a method with AsyncTask disrupts other methods

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

I have a menu with two options. One of the options refreshes the content of the app with web content. I want to dim the ListView that's on the screen and then display a progress bar until the content refreshes. I have methods `startLoadingAnimation()` and `endLoadingAnimation()` that accomplish this. But when I call `refreshArticles()` in between them, they stop working. I have print statements in them that show they execute when they should, but when

```
case R.id.refresh:
    startLoadingAnimation();
    refreshArticles();
    endLoadingAnimation();
```

is executed, only the print statements come through, not the UI changes.

Full activity code:

```
package com.bruno.newsreader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private int numArticles;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private ArrayList<String> articleTitles;
    private ArrayList<String> articleUrls;
    private SQLiteDatabase articleDB;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.refresh:
                startLoadingAnimation();
                refreshArticles();
                endLoadingAnimation();
                return true;
            case R.id.numArticles:
                final NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(getApplicationContext());
                numberPicker.setMaxValue(50);
                numberPicker.setMinValue(5);
                numberPicker.setValue(numArticles);
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Set Number of Articles")
                        .setMessage("This will determine how many articles are stored on your device:")
                        .setView(numberPicker)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                numArticles = numberPicker.getValue();
                                sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("numArticles", numArticles).apply();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .show();
            default:
                return false;

        }
    }

    public class TopArticleDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONArray> {

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            String jsonString = "";
            URL url = urls[0];
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while(data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    jsonString += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return new JSONArray(jsonString);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public class IndividualArticleDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            String jsonString = "";
            URL url = urls[0];
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while(data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    jsonString += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void refreshArticles() {

        String topArticlesUrlString = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty";
        URL topArticlesUrl = null;
        try {
            topArticlesUrl = new URL(topArticlesUrlString);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TopArticleDownloadTask topArticleDownloadTask = new TopArticleDownloadTask();
        JSONArray topArticlesJSON = null;
        try {
            topArticlesJSON = topArticleDownloadTask.execute(topArticlesUrl).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int[] articleIds = new int[numArticles];
        for (int i = 0; i < articleIds.length; i++) {
            try {
                articleIds[i] = topArticlesJSON.getInt(i );
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String articleUrlStart = " https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/";
        String articleUrlEnd = ".json?print=pretty";
        articleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM articles");
        for (int id : articleIds) {
            String articleUrlString = articleUrlStart + id + articleUrlEnd;
            URL articleUrl = null;
            try {
                articleUrl = new URL(articleUrlString);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JSONObject articleJSON = null;
            try {
                IndividualArticleDownloadTask individualArticleDownloadTask = new IndividualArticleDownloadTask();
                articleJSON = individualArticleDownloadTask.execute(articleUrl).get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                String title = articleJSON.getString("title");
                title = title.replaceAll("'", "''");
                String url = articleJSON.getString("url");
                articleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO articles (title, url) VALUES ('" + title + "', '" + url + "')");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        syncArrayListsWithDB();
    }

    private void syncArrayListsWithDB() {
        articleTitles.clear();
        articleUrls.clear();

        Cursor cursor = articleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM articles", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
               String title = cursor.getString(0);
               String url = cursor.getString(1);
               articleTitles.add(title);
               articleUrls.add(url);
               cursor.moveToNext();
           }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, articleTitles);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    private void startLoadingAnimation() {
        System.out.println("start start load");
        listView.setAlpha(.25f);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        System.out.println("end start load");
    }

    private void endLoadingAnimation() {
        System.out.println("start end load");
        listView.setAlpha(1);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        System.out.println("end end load");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        articleTitles = new ArrayList<>();
        articleUrls = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.bruno.newsreader", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        numArticles = sharedPreferences.getInt("numArticles", 10);

        articleDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Data", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        articleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles (title VARCHAR, url VARCHAR)");

        Cursor c = articleDB.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM articles", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int count = c.getInt(0);
        if (count == 0) {
            refreshArticles();
        } else {
            syncArrayListsWithDB();
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReaderActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", articleUrls.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what `refreshArticles()` is actually doing, but I suspect that the answer is "lots of work", and that it's not doing it asynchronously (that is, it's just running along doing its work instead of spawning a new thread to do it and then calling back to you when it is done).

`onOptionsItemSelected()` is executed on the main thread (also called the UI thread). The UI can't be updated while anything is being done on the main thread. So if you're "starting" a loading animation, doing a lot of work, and then "stopping" that animation (all on the main thread), you won't ever actually see the animation run. By the time you're done running your code on the main thread, you've stopped your loading animation.

The solution is to move the work that `refreshArticles()` does to a background thread. There are lots of different ways to accomplish this; reading about `Handler.post(Runnable)` and `AsyncTask` should get you started.

Comment: Thank you! I moved my work to a new `AsyncTask` that calls the two animation methods in its `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute(Result result)` methods. It now works.